# Chrome XMLHttpRequest reference

Tags: google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

Is there any documentation for the current Chrome implementation of XMLHttpRequest similar to this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest

I couldn't find anything on Chrome's dev site and I'd appreciate if anyone can tell me the differences between FF 3.6 and Chrome 8 XHR implementations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Mozilla Developer Network documentation on XMLHTTPRequest has a [browser compatibility chart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Browser_Compatibility) which details the specifics of Chrome's implementation.**

For example, the chart shows that [the comment about `timeout` on an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739587/chrome-xmlhttprequest-reference#comment26961440_4753471) is invalid since Chrome 29.

And since MDN has even more [specific details for Gecko](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Gecko_notes), it's easy to see how the XMLHTTPRequest implementations differ between Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that this is the closest thing to API reference that exists for Chrome/WebKit:
http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Articles/XHR.html

It's far from the quality of Mozilla's docs but I guess that's better than nothing.

Comment: Don’t use this anymore. It’s outdated. – Use the [standard](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html).

Comment: @RobertSiemer Hate to burst your bubble, but the actual behavior of XMLHttpRequest in Chrome is not identical to what's outlined in the standard. It would be nice to have an authoritative description of _Chrome's_ behavior, but I have yet to find such a resource.

Comment: @RobertSiemer I'm not claiming his link is great, just that the standard is not an accurate description of chrome's implementation. Examples of differences: Chrome has neither the timeout attribute nor the ontimeout handler.

Comment: @RobertSiemer the `timeout` comment [isn't valid since Chrome 29](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20902237/7724).

Comment: @StumpyJoePete funnily the day of your comment (2013-08-20) was the release day of Chrome 29, which added `timeout`.

Comment: @RobertSiemer :-/ So... you're saying I could have fixed my problem by turning it off and on again?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the [mozdev website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) you mention, the best know reference for Chrome’s XMLHttpRequest implementation is actually the [standard (draft)](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html). Both cover things like `responseType` way better than any other source I’ve seen.