# Cross Browser Instance in Chrome

Tags: ajax, jquery, cross-browser

I was reading the following guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

It's not mentioned if this cross browser instance (object) of XMLHttpRequest or ActiveXObject is compatible with the Google Chrome browser? If it isn't, what should I be using to include the Google Chrome browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome XMLHttpRequest reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739587/chrome-xmlhttprequest-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActiveXObject` is for MS IE, `XMLHttpRequest` is for the rest (WebKit, Gecko based browsers).

As for supporting `XMLHttpRequest`, Firefox and Chrome are the same.